# Create new Workbook using Excel Services

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services

I want to generate an Excel File using SharePoint. I can make a reference to ExcelServices and want to use the function NewWorkbook.

But I am getting the error which say `Soap Exception: You do not have appropriate permissions to create a new workbook in the specified location`

The following is the code :

```
ExcelService es = new ExcelService();
Status[] outStatus; 
es.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
string sessionId = es.NewWorkbook(@"http://Site/Libary/test.test", null, null, out outStatus);
```

The libary: http:/Site/Libary is an trusted file location.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark but have you checked that excel services have been setup properly?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424405.aspx

a simple guide

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-3-sharepoint_2007__excel_services_-_a_quick_introduction.aspx

hope it point you into the right direction

Answer (score 0):

In this case the cause of the problem is in *path* parameter. The path is a path to a SharePoint document library, not a file ("Remarks" section in article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.excel.server.webservices.excelservice.newworkbook(v=office.14).aspx)